# on what thread dispatch_semaphore_wait is waiting?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to understand better the use of `dispatch_semaphore_wait`. I get the idea of this use but i am not getting on Which thread i am actually wait. if i will do that on the Main thread i will block the main thread, or if i will do it like this:

```
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
            dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
            ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBookRef, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
                dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
            });
            dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
});
```

1. On which thread i will wait ?
2. or if i would use `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT` instead or `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND` ?

Comment: There's no point (and it's inadvisable) in using a semaphore on a global queue like this. Perhaps you can show us what problem you're trying to solve and we can address that.

Answer (score 0):

In 1 and 2 you'd wait on the thread where the DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH and DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND resides. In this case its the same "queue"/thread and the difference relies in the way the scheduler handles the selection of the tasks submitted (high, mid or low priority. Where low is equal to DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND and high as DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH). The do not rely on the UI-thread what so ever. The `dispatch_get_global_queue` call does point to a thread that iOS creates for you. There are lots of guides on the net describing this and how the scheduling of tasks are handled in a multithreaded environment.

Google is your friend ;)

Comment: maybe i didn't got you right, but i didn't understand. if i call this dispatch_semaphore_wait on the DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND it will stuck all the operations that happening on that queue/thread ?

Comment: Yep, and it will wait there until the signal is called since you specified a DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER as time in the semaphore. :)

Comment: @Sosily The global queues are concurrent queues, so you'd be blocking a particular worker thread used by that queue, but not the entire queue. But that doesn't really matter, though, because it's bad practice to unnecessarily block a thread used by a global queue. And in your example, it's entirely unnecessary. Just put whatever code is dependent upon the authorization inside the authorization's completion block and forego the semaphore altogether. There are times you might use your pattern, but only on a custom queue. And at that point, I'd be use a concurrent `NSOperation` rather than GCD.

Comment: Just to clarify more: Semaphores are "counting locks". When you created your semaphore you passed in a "0". That means "0" resources available. When te semaphore then does the dispatch_semaphore_wait, it will take up the only available resource and thus wait there for the time you specified in dispatch_semaphore_wait. If you instead would have passed "1" or any arbitrary number into the semaphore, it would have continued since there was resources available at that time (signal have not been called). If signal is called the "resources" (your "0") are upped with +1. [...]

Comment: ... And thus you can then take it again and so on until your code completes. This is a rather deep subject and is pone to lots of headaches.

Comment: Just to make things clear, This is not my code, i am writing an SDK that use that coded. The problem is that the main Thread stuck from time to time and when i pause it i see semaphore_wait_trap. i guess the code that you saw above is causing this. i am using the global queue DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND so i Think this is reason.

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting to find out synchronously if the user has given address book access I would suggest the following:

```
__block BOOL accessGranted = NO;

dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
    accessGranted = granted;
    if(semaphore) {
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
    }
});
dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
dispatch_release(semaphore);
semaphore = NULL;

return accessGranted;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't be sure in which thread will you wait by calling `dispatch_semaphore_wait()` in the global queue, because:

- global queue is not a single thread, it is a pool of threads.
- only serial queue can be one-threaded, but that is not specified in Apple Documentation.

So, to be sure you are not blocking anything, better to create your own serial queue for waiting the semaphore.